# Get row id value VIA Ajax

Tags: get, tr

Having line :

```
<tr id = "internal_route_id" name ="internal_route_id" value="'.`$data[1]['id']`.'">
```

I want to get the value that returns `$data[1]['id']` and post it VIA AJAX. 
I try like this:

```
data: $("#first_step").serialize()
    + '&internal_route_id=' + $("#internal_route_id").val()
```

Note that `first_step` is the table name. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Use following approach to get the value of tr and post it

<tr id ="internal_route_id" name="internal_route_id" value="'.`$data[1]['id']`.'">

$(function(){
var datavalue=$("#first_step tr").attr('value');
//posting ajax use following
$.ajax({
url:'',
data:{id: datavalue},
success:function(data)
{
        //success code goes here...
}
});
});
```